# make tianium module replace R.layout. or R.id in java class

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

what should I use to replace the R.layout.flash_activity in titanium when building titanium module with ant.
the issue I occured:

error：

```
jason@jason-Inspiron-3542:/workspace/wechat_login/android$ ant
Buildfile: /workspace/wechat_login/android/build.xml

python.set.exec:

python.check:
     [echo] Testing for Python
     [exec] Python 2.7.6

init:

process.annotations:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /workspace/wechat_login/android/build/classes
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
    [javac] warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[kroll.jsonFile, kroll.jsonPackage, kroll.checkTiContext]'
    [javac] /workspace/wechat_login/android/src/com/happystock/wxapi/WXEntryActivity.java:18: error: package R does not exist
    [javac]     setContentView(R.layout.entry);
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] 1 error
    [javac] 1 warning

BUILD FAILED
/home/jason/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.5.0.GA/module/android/build.xml:163: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

code:

```
public class WXEntryActivity extends Activity implements IWXAPIEventHandler{

  private IWXAPI api;
  private static final String APP_ID = "wx44e8a5248161f***";
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.entry);
    api = WXAPIFactory.createWXAPI(this, APP_ID, false);
    api.handleIntent(getIntent(), this);
  }
```

Thanks！

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
int layoutEntry = TiRHelper.getApplicationResource("layout.entry");
setContentView(layoutEntry);
```

The other thing to make sure is that your resource is actually in platform/android/res/layout/entry.xml or it may not be packaged properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution on [this page](http://www.titaniumtutorial.com/2013/11/android-module-development-part-5.html) that worked for me. You can read more about it there. But if you feel like cutting corners, the code is:

```
//declaration
View raingBarWrapper;
int resId_raingBarHolder = -1, resId_ratingBar = -1;

//fetching app package name and resources 
String packageName = proxy.getActivity().getPackageName();
Resources resources = proxy.getActivity().getResources();

//fetching resource id
resId_raingBarHolder = resources.getIdentifier("raingbar_layout", "layout", packageName);
resId_ratingBar = resources.getIdentifier("ratingbar_default","id", packageName);

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
//inflating "raingbar_layout" xml file
raingBarWrapper = inflater.inflate(resId_raingBarHolder, null);

//getting reference to RatingBar component in layout
ratingBar = (RatingBar) raingBarWrapper.findViewById(resId_ratingBar);
setNativeView(raingBarWrapper);

//adding properties to RatingBar component
ratingBar.setNumStars(stars);
ratingBar.setStepSize(stepSize);
ratingBar.setRating(rating);
```